# Jquery - Count amount of items named after a class

Tags: jquery, count, gallery, counter, categories

I am using this script to make a gallery with categories: http://codyhouse.co/gem/content-filter/

My quest is to figure out how to have a total number show by each category link that totals the amount of images in that category. All images are differentiated with a certain class.

So with the below, I'd like to eventually have it to where the category links would look like this:

```
Category 1 (4)
Category 2 (3)
Category 3 (6)
```

With the numbers in parenthesis indicating the amount of images named after each class specified in the category link. Any ideas?

```
<div class="cd-tab-filter">
  <ul class="cd-filters">
    <li class="filter"><a class="selected" href="#0" data-type="all">View All</a></li>
    <li class="filter" data-filter=".category-1"><a href="#0" data-type="category-1">Category 1</a></li>
    <li class="filter" data-filter=".category-2"><a href="#0" data-type="category-2">Category 2</a></li>
    <li class="filter" data-filter=".category-3"><a href="#0" data-type="category-3">Category 3</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div class="cd-gallery">
  <ul>
    <li class="mix category-1"></li>
    <li class="mix category-1"></li>
    <li class="mix category-1"></li>
    <li class="mix category-1"></li>

    <li class="mix category-2"></li>
    <li class="mix category-2"></li>
    <li class="mix category-2"></li>

    <li class="mix category-3"></li>
    <li class="mix category-3"></li>
    <li class="mix category-3"></li>
    <li class="mix category-3"></li>
    <li class="mix category-3"></li>
    <li class="mix category-3"></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [.length](http://api.jquery.com/length/) to get the count of elements with the given classes.

```
$('.category-1').length
$('.category-2').length
$('.category-3').length
```

These length values can be appended to the each filter elements

```
$('.cd-filters li[data-filter]').each(function(){
  var reqClass = $(this).data('filter'); // <--- this will get classes .category-1, .category-2 and .category-3
  var len = ' ('+$(reqClass).length+')'; // <--- this will do $('.category-1').length
  $(this).append(len);
});
```

If the total of all the categories needs to be added as well, have a variable and sum the lengths like this

```
var total = 0;
$('.cd-filters li[data-filter]').each(function(){
  var reqClass = $(this).data('filter'); // <--- this will get classes .category-1, .category-2 and .category-3
  var len = +$(reqClass).length; // <--- this will do $('.category-1').length
  $(this).append(' (' + len + ')' );
  total += len
});
// use this total to append to first li (View ALL)
$('li [data-type="all"]').append(' (' + total + ')' );
```

Here is a demo **http://jsbin.com/qudejo/edit?html,js,output**

Comment: thanks a lot! Sorry I'm a total newb with jquery. How exactly would I get that function to make it show in the category links?

Comment: no worries. I updated my answer with a demo. See if that gives you a start

Comment: nothing crucial, just curious. If I had a category link that showed ALL images in all categories, any way I could append the total for that link too?